# Convertir tipo de dato BigSerial de string a bigint - PostgreSQL con NestJS

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Muy buenas. Tengo una tabla con el **id** como tipo de dato **bigserial** en PostgreSQL.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente estoy utilizando NestJS para el backend, y en el momento de crear un nuevo registro, siempre el tipo de dato **id** me lo pasa como string, Haciendo las pruebas con Postman:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en NestJS, Mi controller se ve así:

```
@Post()
  async create(@Body() payload: CreatePuestoFronterizoDto) {
    const nuevo = await this.puestosFronterizosService.create(payload);
    const data = {
      data: nuevo,
      message: 'Registro creado correctamente',
    };
    return data;
  }
```

Mi dto así:

```
@IsOptional()
  @ApiProperty()
  readonly id: string;
```

Mi entity así:

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment', { type: 'bigint' })
  id: string;
```

Sin embargo, siempre a la hora de crear el registro, lo pasa como string.

Answer (score 0):

Proba agregando `app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }));`
al main.ts. Esto te deberia hacer la transfromacion de tipos del DTO.

Comment: Ya he agregado lo que mencionas en el main.ts @DSabalsa pero debo de alguna manera implementar el transform en algo más?

Comment: Con la libreria https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-transformer, deberias poder hacer algo de la forma:

```
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';

@Type(() => Number)
@IsOptional()
@ApiProperty()
 readonly id: number;
```